# How to write resume (CV)

Tags: templates, cv

I'm a fresh graduate student, and I want to write a resume using Latex, what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: @A.khalaf: If you have successfully downloaded/installed [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), open up [`template.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.tex) and compile to see what the output looks like. From there you can insert your own content and perhaps change the theme.

Comment: @Werner : I did it, But it does not work: {**'moderncv.cls'** not found}, Can i install it manually ?

Comment: @A.khalaf: No, it's best to follow the instruction provided in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) rather than installing things manually.